# React-Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm coming up with an error,

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits
the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

on a function that GETS api data from axios. This is the first time this error is showing up for me.

The errors show up when I'm loading the page.

The culprit might be in this `useEffect` according to react.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axiosInstance.get('all/buckets/').then((res) => {
    const allBuckets = res.data;
    setAppState({ loading: false, buckets: allBuckets });
    console.log(res.data);
  });
}, [setAppState]);
```

Here the complete component:

```
export default function GetUserBuckets() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const ListLoading = LoadingComponent(UserBuckets);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    posts: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get('all/buckets/')
      .then((res) => {
        const allBuckets = res.data;
        setAppState({
          loading: false,
          buckets: allBuckets,
        });
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }, [setAppState]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.text}>
      <h1>Buckets</h1>
      <ListLoading
       isLoading={appState.loading}
       buckets={appState.buckets}
      />
      <Container className={classes.createBucket}>
        <CreateDialog />
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error is also very inconsistent, it sometimes appears and sometimes it does not, based on the user requesting the data. It could be a backend issue, but currently trying to see if I can tidy up my useEffect better to fix this issue.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: setState is a stable function provided by react, even on rerenders. Given that, adding as dependency or not will not trigger an infinite loop whatsoever. The error is likely coming from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thats what I think, however I have not been able to solve this issue.

Comment: can you share `LoadingComponent` and/or your GetUserBuckets's parent, or even provide a sandbox? your `useEffect` seems to be a symptom not the root cause. Something else is causing your component to rerender indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not passing `setAppState` as a dependency to your `useEffect` hook.

Just use an empty array, so that it only runs once when your `GetUserBuckets` component is mounted.

Refactor your useEffect to look like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axiosInstance.get('all/buckets/').then((res) => {
    const allBuckets = res.data;
    setAppState({ loading: false, buckets: allBuckets });
    console.log(res.data);
  };
}, []); // Removed the setAppState here
```

Comment: Did you try this? @woof

Comment: because `setState` is a stable function provided by react, meaning that you can have it as dependency and it will not trigger a infinite loop. you can remove it if you want, but it won't have any influence on solving a infinite loop issue.

Comment: fortunee, yes I tried and I couldn't get the problem to solve itself.